# Undefined Variable on this tutorial on PHP with Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Please help me fix this undefined variable I copy and pasted this code on my create.php and when i hit the create button on the home page i get this:

> Notice: Undefined variable: fnameError in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\TestCRUD\create.php on line 70
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: lnameError in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\TestCRUD\create.php on line 75
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: ageError in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\TestCRUD\create.php on line 80

Notice: Undefined variable: genderError in C:\xampp\htdocs\TestCRUD\create.php on line 89

```
<?php
if ( !empty($_POST)) {
    require 'db.php';
    // validation errors
    $fnameError     = null;
    $lnameError     = null;
    $ageError       = null;
    $genderError    = null;

    // post values
    $fname  = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname  = $_POST['lname'];
    $age    = $_POST['age'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];

    // validate input
    $valid = true;
    if(empty($fname)) {
        $fnameError = 'Please enter First Name';
        $valid = false;
    }

    if(empty($lname)) {
        $lnameError = 'Please enter Last Name';
        $valid = false;
    }

    if(empty($age)) {
        $ageError = 'Please enter Age';
        $valid = false;
    }

    if(empty($gender)) {
        $genderError = 'Please select Gender';
        $valid = false;
    }

    // insert data
    if ($valid) {
        $PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (fname,lname,age,gender) values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($fname,$lname,$age,$gender));
        $PDO = null;
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">

                <div class="row">
                <div class="row">
                    <h3>Create a User</h3>
                </div>

                <form method="POST" action="">
<div class="form-group <?php echo !empty($fnameError)?'has-error':'';?>">
    <label for="inputFName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="inputFName" value="<?php echo !empty($fname)?$fname:'';?>" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $fnameError;?></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group <?php echo !empty($lnameError)?'has-error':'';?>">
    <label for="inputLName">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="inputLName" value="<?php echo !empty($lname)?$lname:'';?>" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $lnameError;?></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group <?php echo !empty($ageError)?'has-error':'';?>">
    <label for="inputAge">Age</label>
    <input type="number" required="required" class="form-control" id="inputAge" value="<?php echo !empty($age)?$age:'';?>" name="age" placeholder="Age">
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $ageError;?></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group <?php echo !empty($genderError)?'has-error':'';?>">
    <label for="inputGender">Gender</label>
    <select class="form-control" required="required" id="inputGender" name="gender" >
    <option></option>
    <option value="male" <?php echo $gender == 'male'?'selected':'';?>>Male</option>
    <option value="female" <?php echo $gender == 'female'?'selected':'';?>>Female</option>
    </select>
<span class="help-block"><?php echo $genderError;?></span>

</div>

<div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="index.php">Back</a>
</div>
</form>

</div> <!-- /row -->
</div> <!-- /container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're displaying errors even when the variables haven't been set. That brings up the notice you see. You can avoid them by checking if they are set first using `isset` or `empty`

```
<?= isset($someError) ? $someError : '' ?>
```

Comment: can you please help me modify this code im still new to bootstrap, pdo and php. so i'll modify the span tag?

Comment: inside your `span` you have `<?php echo $fnameError;?>` - replace those with `<?php echo isset($fnameError) ? $fnameError : '';?>`

Comment: got it working man i finally understood the nature of the problem thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

use isset();

```
// post values
    $fname  = isset($_POST['fname']);
    $lname  = isset($_POST['lname']);
    $age    = isset($_POST['age']);
    $gender = isset($_POST['gender']);
```

Answer (score 0):

On the lines like the following, you need to check that the variables have a value before trying to use them. So the following code...

`<span class="help-block"><? echo $fnameError; ?></span>`

...should be changed to this:

`<span class="help-block"><?= isset($fnameError) ? $fnameError : ''; ?></span>`

To prevent these errors being picked up and displayed you could also turn PHP error reporting off but fixing the problem is preferable:

```
<?php
error_reporting('off');
ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
```

Comment: got it working finally understood the problem so i was continuouly printing the error msg without checking if the error variable has value. you're the best man! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can added a hidden type input to form for process after send parameters:

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['h'])) {
....//your process
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
.....<!--your input-->
<input type="hidden" name="h" value="true">
<button type="submit"> submit </button>
</form>
```